# Take first non-empty regex.exec() capturing group

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I run this

```
var text = "abc def ghi";
var regex = /a(bc)|d(e)f|(gh)i/g
while (match = regex.exec(text)) {
  console.log(match);
}
// 0=abc, 1=bc, 2=undefined, 3=undefined
// 0=def, 1=undefined, 2=e, 3=undefined
// 0=ghi, 1=undefined, 2=undefined, 3=gh
```

In every iteration of the loop, I'd like to retrieve the matching capturing group, so only bc, e, gh. Is it possible without manually checking for undefined?

Comment: It is not possible with JS RegExp. You will have to check for `undefined`.  Or rely on lookarounds (note that lookbehind is the ECMAScript 2018 feature that is currently implemented in Chrome): `/(?<=a)bc|(?<=d)e(?=f)|gh(?=i)/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can avoid the check (unless you can use lookarounds as [Wiktor pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50188503/take-first-non-empty-regex-exec-capturing-group/50188586#comment87393729_50188503)), but it need not be long-winded:

```js
var text = "abc def ghi";
var regex = /a(bc)|d(e)f|(gh)i/g
while (match = regex.exec(text)) {
  var first = match.reduce((p, entry, i) => p && i != 1 ? p : entry);
  console.log(first);
}
```

Note that that ignores all falsy values, since your capture groups will either not match at all (giving you `undefined`) or match a non-empty string, so we don't have to worry about `""`.

Alternately, instead of

```
var first = match.reduce((p, entry, i) => p && i != 1 ? p : entry);
```

you could use

```
var first = match.slice(1).reduce((p, entry) => p ? p : entry);
```

...but it involves a temporary array.

Answer (score 0):

You will get array in `match` so you can also add a logic where you traverse the array from the end and get the first value that is not `undefined`. Something like this below:

```js
var text = "abc def ghi";
var regex = /a(bc)|d(e)f|(gh)i/g;
var finalMatch = [];
var match;
while (match = regex.exec(text)) {
  for(var i=match.length; i>0; i--){
    if(match[i]){
       finalMatch.push(match[i]);
       break;
    }
  }
}
console.log(finalMatch);
```

Comment: The whole point of the question was if it was possible without manually checking